# What kind of differential equation is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

What kind of differential equation is this?

$x^2*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x*\frac{dy}{dx}+(x+1)*y=0$

It's close to an euler equation which is

$x^2*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x*\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$

but it's also close to Bessel equation which is

$x^2*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x*\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2+a^2)*y=0$

But does not fit either one right. Please let me know how to go about solving it?

Comment: We have been learning about taylor series, can we use taylor series to solve for the general equation of this?

Comment: Homogeneous second order linear differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ODE belongs to the family of the Bessel equations. The solutions of the more general form of ODEs :
$$x^2y''+(1-3p)xy'+(\lambda^2q^2x^{2q}+p^2-\nu^2q^2)y=0$$
are : $\qquad\qquad y(x)=c_1 x^p J_\nu(\lambda x^q)+c_2 x^p J_{-\nu}(\lambda x^q)$

In the present case : $p=0 \:;\: q=1/2 \:;\: \lambda=2 \:;\: \nu=\pm 2i $
$$y(x)=c_1 J_{2i}(2 \sqrt{x})+c_2 J_{-2i}(2 \sqrt{x})$$

Comment: ah wow, that's awesome. Do you have any references that would be good for me to learn from?

Comment: This kind of equations can be found in the handbooks of special functions. For example : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html , eqs.(3-5).